# How to replace existing child element classnames with new ones?

Tags: javascript

I have a shuffled list of cards. I cannot figure out how to replace the existing board of cards with this shuffled list.

```js
let card_source = document.querySelectorAll('li.card');
let icon_class_list = []; 
let card_list = [];

for (let i of card_source) {
    card_list.push(i);
}
 
for (let icon_class of card_list){
    icon_class_list.push(icon_class.lastElementChild)
} 

// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
    var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

    while (currentIndex !== 0) {
        randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
        currentIndex -= 1;
        temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
        array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
        array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
    }

    return array;
}
    
let shuffled = shuffle(icon_class_list);

for (let card_icon_space of card_source) {
    for (let card_item of shuffled) {
        card_icon_space.classList.replace('card_icon_space.children[0]', 'card_item');
    }
}
```

```html
<ul class="deck">
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-diamond"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-anchor"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
            </li>
            <li class="card">
                <i class="fa fa-cube"></i>
            </li>
</ul>
```

Expected results: The existing board of cards is now different, with a shuffled deck.
Actual: No difference

Comment: ReferenceError: card_list is not defined

Comment: `.replace(card_icon_space.children[0].className, 'card_item')`

Comment: @allesandrio : Thanks! This was helpful. For some reason it is still not replacing the existing board of cards.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner As cale_b just mentioned, you should focus on the DOM elements rather than the strings of the classNames (assuming that's OP intent by using `replace()`). See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308183/2813224)

Comment: @zer00ne : Thanks! I am new to Javascript (week 1) and your feedback is very helpful.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner Ok...did you review my answer? Comment / vote / accept over [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56308183/2813224). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: @ zer00ne : Yes. This did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner great! If you get stuck animating the cards to flip just post a question and then drop a comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of manipulating classNames use the DOM and treat each tag as a DOM Object. In the demo the "ghost" document is a [**documentFragment**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) which is used to keep the shuffled `<li>` until the `<ul>` is cleared of the "old" `<li>` using [Range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range). Admittedly, this may seem overkill, but no matter how many `<li>` you have, it won't slow down. Details commented in demo.

```js
// Reference <ul>
const deck = document.querySelector('.deck');
// Create a "ghost" document
let newDeck = document.createDocumentFragment();
// Collect <li> into a NodeList and convert to array
const unshuffled = [...deck.querySelectorAll('.card')];
// Copy the array
let cards = [...unshuffled];
// shuffle() new array
let shuffled = shuffle(cards);
// Add each <li> from new array to 'ghost' deck
for (let card of shuffled) {
  newDeck.appendChild(card);
}

// Clear <li> from <ul>
let oldCards = document.createRange();
oldCards.selectNodeContents(deck);
oldCards.deleteContents();

// Add 'ghost' deck to <ul>
deck.appendChild(newDeck);

// Shuffle function from http://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976
function shuffle(array) {
  var currentIndex = array.length,
    temporaryValue, randomIndex;

  while (currentIndex !== 0) {
    randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
    currentIndex -= 1;
    temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
    array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
    array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }

  return array;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<ul class="deck">
  <li class="card">
    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="far fa-paper-plane"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fas fa-anchor"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fas fa-bolt"></i>
  </li>
  <li class="card">
    <i class="fas fa-cube"></i>
  </li>
</ul>
```